# Enable/Disable command button based on datatable errors

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I am using PrimeFace 5.0.
I have a datatable with a editable date field. 
Outside the data-table is a comman button, I want to enable/disable the command button based on the errors on the page.Here is the codes for teh common button.

```
<p:commandButton value="xxxx" id="xxxBtn" type="submit" partialSubmit="true" ajax="true" update="@form" disabled="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}"
actionListener="#{xxxBean.xxx}" styleClass="Win95 Fnone marAuto">
```

The command button is disabled when there are error messages on the page, on one or multiple rows in the data-table, but if I correct one of the rows error messages the button becomes enabled, even though there are errors existing on the other rows in the data-table.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
{not empty facesContext.messageList}
```

to

```
{not empty facesContext.messageList?true:false}
```

Comment: Why? What is the difference? Please add some text explaining why this is the solution

Comment: This solution did not fix the issue.                                                           {not empty facesContext.messageList} would evaluate to true or false and the button would enable/disable. the issue was that the button would be enabled even if one of the row errors was fixed and the other rows in the datatable still had errors.